# Printer is "sptting" black ink stains

Tags: printer, ink, toner, cartridge

My printer is an HP Laserjet P1005.

When printing, it's currently randomly "spitting" black ink stains (a few per page but on lots of pages).

Should I replace the printer or the ink cartridge?

(I don't not currently have time to sent it to a repair service and wait for return, I really need to solve this faster.)

Answer (score 1):

The Laserjet P1005 is a black and white laser. The only component that can produce the problem you describe is the drum. In your case the drum is part of the toner cartridge.

So replace the toner cartridge.